# Titanium: Issues installing Cloud Push (ti.cloudpush)

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I am having some odd issues with installing `ti.cloudpush`.

First, when I add `ti.cloudpush` to my Alloy project, using the Accelerator Studio's TiApp Editor, it says the only version available is `4.0.3`.

This is odd, as the following command shows the latest version of `ti.cloudpush` is actually v3.4.0:

```
$ gittio info ti.cloudpush

[INFO]  ti.cloudpush searching...

 id: ti.cloudpush
 type: module
 description: ACS Push notifications for Android
 title: cloudpush
 tags:
 platforms: android
 user: torneseumprogramador
 repo: aplicativo
 versions:

   version: 3.4.0
   datetime: 2016-07-22 20:29:16
   platforms: android
   dist:
   path:
   tree: 0360101006acbad47526f920bda3289898c398f9
```

This is also verified by going on the following:

https://github.com/torneseumprogramador/aplicativo/tree/master/modules/ti.cloudpush

and

http://gitt.io/component/ti.cloudpush

Nonetheless I continue to run my Android application using the following command

```
$ appc run -T device -p Android
```

However, I then get the error:

```
[ERROR] Conflicting jar files detected:
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] The following modules have different "google-play-services-base.jar" files
[ERROR]    ti.map         (version 3.3.0) (hash=6ac3fc6163fe93aee502091a3012193c)
[ERROR]    ti.cloudpush   (version 4.0.3) (hash=291a4dc25f913c6de3415675f52cc7fa)
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] You can either select a version of these modules where the conflicting jar file is the same or you
[ERROR] can try copying the jar file from one module's "lib" folder to the other module's "lib" folder.
```

So I then decided to use an older version of ti.cloudpush by changing the tiapp.xml to use this:

```
<module platform="android" version="3.4.0">ti.cloudpush</module>
```

But then it gives me the error:

```
[ERROR] Could not find all required Titanium Modules:
[ERROR]    id: ti.cloudpush      version: 3.4.0  platform: android       deploy-type: test
```

So I then resorted to using gittio and did the following command (as suggested by http://gitt.io/component/ti.cloudpush but I then get the following error:

```
$ gittio install ti.cloudpush
[INFO]  ti.cloudpush searching...
[ERROR] ti.cloudpush:commonjs no distributable available
[ERROR] ti.cloudpush:android no distributable available
[ERROR] ti.cloudpush:ios no distributable available
```

What is going on and how do I install `ti.cloudpush`? This used to be working for me before.

Answer (score 0):

ti.cloudpush is a module by Appcelerator. Gitt.io is a website not maintained by Apccelerator (it is a community effort).

The reason your `3.4.0` version cannot be found is because it probably doesn't support the SDK you're working with.

By looking at the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.CloudPush) it appears you don't need to be downloading the module, but just including it should work just fine. If you use Appcelerator Studio you should also see it listed when you click the "+" icon on the right in the tiapp-editor when you're adding a module.

Comment: Yes that's what I did initially. But it only shows version `4.0.3`. And then I get that conflicting jar error.

Comment: yeah you'll need to adjust the `jar` files ;)

Comment: I don't understand. How?

Comment: it is in the error message: ```[ERROR] You can either select a version of these modules where the conflicting jar file is the same or you
[ERROR] can try copying the jar file from one module's "lib" folder to the other module's "lib" folder.
```

Comment: Well I tried selecting a different version of `ti.cloudpush`, but it gives me a "Could not find" error, as I said in my question. I also don't see any module folder for either the map or cloudpush in my `lib` folder.